# Why use keys filter instead of columns.slice()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why is the author using

```
d3.keys(cars[0]).filter...
```

instead of using

```
cars.columns.slice(1)
```

..? The slice effectively returns the same information without having to do any logic below.

```
  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1),
   y = {};

  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0]));
  }));
```

Data for this is

```
name,economy (mpg),cylinders,displacement (cc),power (hp),weight (lb),0-60 mph (s),year
AMC Ambassador Brougham,13,8,360,175,3821,11,73
AMC Ambassador DPL,15,8,390,190,3850,8.5,70
AMC Ambassador SST,17,8,304,150,3672,11.5,72
```

Source: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1341021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of that code is the creator of D3. Of course, he would probably prefer the second snippet. However, that code is using D3 v3.x, and there is no `columns` property in the data array in that version of D3.

Let's see this in the following snippets.

First, using D3 v3.x:

```js
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

console.log("using d3.keys: " + d3.keys(data[0]));
console.log("using data.columns: " + data.columns);
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,economy (mpg),cylinders,displacement (cc),power (hp),weight (lb),0-60 mph (s),year
AMC Ambassador Brougham,13,8,360,175,3821,11,73
AMC Ambassador DPL,15,8,390,190,3850,8.5,70
AMC Ambassador SST,17,8,304,150,3672,11.5,72</pre>
```

You can see that `d3.keys(data[0])` works, while `data.columns` returns undefined.

Now using D3 v4.x:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

console.log("using d3.keys: " + d3.keys(data[0]));
console.log("using data.columns: " + data.columns);
```

```css
pre{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,economy (mpg),cylinders,displacement (cc),power (hp),weight (lb),0-60 mph (s),year
AMC Ambassador Brougham,13,8,360,175,3821,11,73
AMC Ambassador DPL,15,8,390,190,3850,8.5,70
AMC Ambassador SST,17,8,304,150,3672,11.5,72</pre>
```

Both `d3.keys(data[0])` and `data.columns` work, and give you the same result.